# How do I use Javascript to force cursor to specific form field when form field has a name with brackets?

Tags: javascript, forms, cakephp, cursor

I am using CakePHP as my framework.

On page load, I want to force the cursor to a specific form field where name="data[Project][title]"

I'm trying to use javascript:

This works fine if I change the name to something without brackets, but fails to work with this form name.  I have to use this form field name because of how CakePHP processes my form data.

**Is there a workaround or another simple way to force the cursor to this form field?**

Here is the code I currently have (if you change "data[Project][title]" to "formField" it works):

```
<body onLoad="document.searchForm.data[Project][title].focus();">

<form action="http://beta.industrialinterface.com/users/mainadd/" method="post" id="create-form" name="searchForm">

<input id="main-input" type="text" class="title-limit" name="data[Project][title]" onClick="this.value='';limitText(60);" onKeyDown="limitText(60);return true;" onKeyUp="limitText(60);return true;" />
```

Comment: You say, "This works fine if I change the name to something without brackets." Can you show us the code you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code? Because otherwise you could simply do:

```
document.getElementById('id_for_your_input').focus();
```

Comment: It seems that he doesn't have/isn't capable of setting an `id` for the input (I'm gathering that CakePHP is generating the form for him).

Comment: he can still set an id, though. cakePHP would allow that :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a form and have access to the form element you can do

```
formelement['data[project][title]'].focus();
```

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/fqgxv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) for this. Note that it returns an array.

Ex:

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementsByName("data[Project][title]")[0].focus();">
```